# import multiple files from a folder and append the password protected data

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

Based on the @Gregory Demin answer, I have imported the password protected xlsx file using the below code.

```
filename = "Data - x.xlsx"
xl.workbook.open(filename, password = "******")
new_path = paste0(tempdir(), "\\", filename)
xl()[["Activeworkbook"]]$saveas(new_path, AccessMode=xl.constants$xlExclusive)
#xl()[["Activesheet"]]$Unprotect(password = "******)
df= xl[b11:dz46]
xl.workbook.close()
unlink(new_path)
names(df) <- df[1,]
df <- df[-1,]###Changing the first row as header
```

This work perfectly for me. However, the problem is I have 100 files in a folder and each of that has different password. So I need to repeat this again and again. Is there a way that i can do this one go. Also, I want to append all data finally into 1 file with the file name in separate column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataframe with a column for file and associated password. Modify your code so that it is a function and loop though  the dataframe you created using the rows as arguments.

```
#useful functions
list.files()
```

Comment: Actually, I have a separate dataframe (i.e., pwd_df) with 2 columns file.name and password for each file. But not sure how to loop it here to get the password automatically for each file

Comment: Beyond someone coding it for you, you need to read some documentation on the R programming langage.

[R_inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference document. Based on the input, I somehow constructed the loop with the dynamic password and successfully got the desire output. I really appreciate your efforts for replying.